# Retrieve the first search result from Google using Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been trying to get the first search result using the below code. The code works fine for some cases, but for some cases the output that it provides is an incomplete one.

COde:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

research_later = "ABCD filetype:pdf"
goog_search = "http://google.com/search?q=" + research_later


r = requests.get(goog_search)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('cite').text)
```

Output:

```
www.altogetherbetter.org.uk/.../5-assetbasedcommunitydevelopment.pdf
```

The actual output should be:

```
http://www.altogetherbetter.org.uk/Data/Sites/1/5-assetbasedcommunitydevelopment.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cite tag does not contain the whole link. You might want to get it from the "a" tag. Try this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'https://(.)+')
elem = soup.find('a',attrs={'href':re.compile(r'/url?')})['href']
regex.search(elem).group()
```

This will give you the link but you might need to format it a bit more with another regex.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that I used to resolve my issue. I have downloaded the file which was my ultimate goal after finding the web link.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
    research_later = "ABCD filetype:pdf"

    driver.get("http://google.com/search?q="+research_later)
    elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#rso > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > h3 > a").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's no need for `selenium` or `regex`.

You're looking for this to get the very first link (*have a look at [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the element in your browser*):

```py
first_link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
# https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors
```

Also, the next problem might be because is that no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) specified and Google will block a request eventually and you'll receive a completely different HTML.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "ABCD filetype:pdf",   # query
  "gl": "us",                 # country to search from
  "hl": "en"                  # language
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

first_link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
print(first_link)

# https://resources.depaul.edu/abcd-institute/resources/Documents/WhatisAssetBasedCommunityDevelopment.pdf
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want fast, rather than figuring out why certain things don't work as expected and you don't have to maintain the parser over time.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "bABCD filetype:pdf",
    "hl": "en",
    "gl": "us",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

first_link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
print(first_link)

# https://dohcoey14i4kf.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/despiece_maquina_mc507_0.pdf
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.